# Promise inside Array.map or loop alternative?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

I was wondering how you would solve the following issue. I have an upload component which accepts multiple files. So `onDrop` gives me `accepted` and `rejected` files (based on extension and size).

From those `accepted` I need to figure out if they have the correct dimensions and I'm would like to use the [`browser-image-size` package](https://github.com/cesarandreu/browser-image-size).

This package returns a promise, but as you can see below I need to check this for each file in the `accepted` argument provided. I tried the following but as you can see this always returns an emty array and undefined.

How do I solve this issue?

```js
const checkDimensions = (file) => {
  return Promise.resolve(file);
}

const handleFiles = (accepted, rejected) => {
  const acceptedFiles = [];
  const errors = [];

  accepted.map(file =>
    checkDimensions(file)
    .catch((error) => errors.push(error))
    .then((file) => acceptedFiles.push(file))
  );

  // both log empty array
  console.log(acceptedFiles);
  console.log(errors);
}

// Logs undefined 
console.log(handleFiles(['test file']))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your console logs are executed before the `checkDimensions` had a chance to complete it's work.

```
const handleFiles = (accepted, rejected) => {
  const acceptedFiles = [];
  const errors = [];

  accepted.map(file => checkDimensions(file)
    .then(file => acceptedFiles.push(file), error => errors.push(error))
    .then(() => {
      console.log(acceptedFiles);
      console.log(errors);
    });
  );
}
```

A `then` has an optional second parameter. The difference between `catch` followed by `then` versus `then` with 2 arguments is subtle: If `checkDimensions` decides to reject a file, the `acceptedFiles.push(file)` will still be executed.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know there was an actual difference in behavior doing the `.catch()` and `.then()` or `.then(success, error)`. Very confusing in my oppinion. Any way it is possible to stop the `.then()` methods after a `.catch()` statement?

Comment: `return Promise.reject()` in a then/catch will not execute following thens. If using Bluebird you can use [reflection](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/reflect.html)